# Check if a given index exists in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std

I need index access to my `std::vector`, and therefore I must check if an index is already available to first delete them, and then set a new value.

Here's my setter function:

```
void SetVector(int position, int value) {
    std::vector<int>iterator it = testVector.begin();
    // need a check here
    testVector.insert(it-testVector.begin()+position, value);
}
```

Or is this the wrong C++ collection for my needs? (should grow dynamically, so no `std:array` possible). Could use a `std::map` but maybe it's also possible with `std::vector`.

Comment: What you describe in the text would best be done by saying `if (position < testVector.size()) { testVector[position] = value; }`. But what your code does seems rather different... can you explain?

Comment: Do you want to insert a new item, or change an existing value?

Comment: Insert if the index is not set or if set first delete it and save the new value at this position!

Comment: Since you have a vector of simple integers, there is nothing to delete. Simply overriding the existing value `testVector[position] = value;` is fine.

Comment: what do you mean by an index being set? At any given time, a vector has size N, so the valid indices are 0 to N-1. The size fo the vector gives you the currently valid indices.

Comment: Rather checking whether the container is the most appropriate, you should consider whether the design is appropriate. Can you describe in simple words how the function should act? Provide a couple of examples of the sequence before and after a call to `SetVector` with different parameters? (`position < size()`, `position > size()`...)

Comment: Switched back to std::map where key=index and value=value! Anyway thx for your help!

Answer (score 12):

The requirements aren't entirely clear from the question, but I'm assuming that you want to end up with `testVector[position] == value`, whether or not `position` was in range to begin with.

First grow the vector if it's too small. This will insert zero-values after whatever is already there.

```
if (position >= testVector.size()) {
    testVector.resize(position+1);
}
```

Then assign the element you want to set:

```
testVector[position] = value;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote this. `resize()` will insert a default element which you then overwrite with the value that you actually want. Much better to use `push_back()`.

Comment: @TemplateRex: `push_back()` won't necessarily insert it at the desired position, so that would be wrong. This is the simplest way to do what the OP seems to want; I'll add an alternative for when you really want to avoid the cost of inserting and overwriting an element.

Comment: tnx for updating! +1 now

Comment: @TemplateRex We are talking about a vector of `int`. Chances are that a combination of `resize()` and `push_back()` makes things rather worse in terms of performance.

Comment: @jogojapan why? because `push_back()` might call `reserve()`?

Comment: @TemplateRex Generally speaking, because `push_back()` will have to do many of the things that `resize()` has to do, too. E.g. updating the member that stores the size, and, yes, allocating memory.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Because `resize` followed by `push_back` might cause two allocations, while a single `resize` can't cause more than one. So perhaps you'd want to complicate things further with a `reserve`; and then you'll probably find that you have far more extra operations than you would just by using the simple version.

Comment: @TemplateRex: In fact, I'm going to remove my update, since (as jogogapan says) you'll be modifying the size and capacity multiple times if you try to jump through hoops to avoid the extra assignment. Feel free to restore your downvote if you disagree.

Comment: @jogojapan OK, I see that it is a tradeoff where `push_back()` saves an assignment, possibly at the expense of bookkeeping instructions. For large types though this would change, so in general one should measure. The allocation stuff would probably an advantage though, because the implied logarithmic growth has the least amount of reallocations if it is called repeatedly.

Comment: @MikeSeymour no I agree now that the simpler code is probably best here, unless measurements indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe the question is clear. If you want

> "to first delete them, and then set a new value."

this might work

```
void SetVector(int position, int value) {
    if (position < testVector.size()) {
        testVector[position] = value;
    }
    else {
        testVector.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

You should really make the `int position` the `testVector`'s `size_type`.

Comment: +1 for bringing up `size_type`. `push_back` of course will ignore the `position`. Not sure if that's intended.

Comment: @jogojapan re push_back... I know, but the comment says "Insert if the index is not set" which could mean anything.

Comment: Absolutely. My comment was merely to make the questioner aware of this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::vector::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) who throw an exception if you don't have anything at this index.

> The function automatically checks whether n is within the bounds of
>   valid elements in the vector, throwing an out_of_range exception if it
>   is not (i.e., if n is greater or equal than its size). This is in
>   contrast with member operator[], that does not check against bounds.

And since you get a reference on the object at the given index, you can change/delete the value

```
void SetVector(int position, int value) {
   try
    {
       testVector.at(position) = value;
    }
   catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
      testVector.resize(position + 1);
      testVector[position] = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need `resize(position+1)`, not `reserve(position)`, to make `position` a valid index.

Comment: @MikeSeymour http://ideone.com/oh7Hf5 it's working, I'm not getting your point. Because I see that your argue with push_back and all but we really don't know what the op want to do with this array

Comment: It's not "working". Your code is writing beyond the end of the vector, giving undefined behaviour - which is certainly not what the OP wants. Unless it's resized to at least `position+1`, `position` is not a valid index.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You're right, I don't know why I have said such a wrong thing. I have edited my answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

first get an iterator for your vector by using

```
 std::vector<int>::iterator it;
```

`it = myvector.begin();`

```
for (it=myvector.begin(); it<myvector.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
```

Using thsi iterator you can traverse all elements and perform respective operation like remove element